# Can't establish communication between redis and app in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to run a node app in a docker container. It depends on Redis.

The following is the `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"
services:
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - app-network
    command: ["redis-server", "--bind", "redis", "--port", "6379"]
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3123:3123"
    depends_on:
      - redis
    networks:
      - app-network
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile for building the app is as follows

```
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /app
COPY .env.docker .env
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --silent
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3123
RUN npm start
```

Inside Node, the config is as follows

```
const redis = require('redis');

const { REDIS_HOST, REDIS_PORT } = process.env;

const client = redis.createClient({
  host: REDIS_HOST,
  port: REDIS_PORT,
});

client.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('redis connected successfully');
});

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('Redis is ready to use');
});

client.on('error', function (error) {
  console.error(error);
});

// promisify redis client methods
const { promisify } = require('util');

client.get = promisify(client.get);
client.set = promisify(client.set);

module.exports = client;
```

.env.local

```
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

.env.docker

```
REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

> **I am running docker on a windows machine using WSL.**

Comment: I am guessing that 6379 is not the default port for redis, so it is probably not exposed in the Dockerfile of the image you are using, you can create your custom image and expose that port in your own Dockerfile.
Otherwise the issue may be that your node app is using the wrong host to look for redis

Comment: How are you configuring your node app to connect to redis? I don't see any configuration either in your Dockerfile or in your docker-compose.yml that tells it what host and port to use.

Comment: @Nathanael 6379 _is_ the default port for Redis, but even so, "expose" means almost nothing in modern Docker; you don't need to expose ports for inter-container connections (or anything else really).  (Contrast with "publish", which you need to do to make a container accessible from outside of Docker space.)

Comment: @larsks I just added the code that I am using to connect the Redis server and as well the env variables. Please look into it.

Comment: Do you expect that `.env` file to have any impact? I'm not familar with node. Can you confirm that your application is actually trying to contact host `redist` on port `6379`?

Comment: @larsks yep..! the app is trying to connect on port 6379.

Comment: @larsks when ever I am executing the docker-compose, a network is being created but when I inspect network I can see that no containers are linked to that network. I don't know why that's happening